# Show that for each $n > 0$, $(1+1/n)^n \le e$

Tags: real-analysis

The question wants me to use the fact that $1 + x \le e^x$ but not sure how to do that. I would have used induction otherwise.

Any idea of how to do it using this fact?

Comment: Let $x=1/n$ and see what happens.

Comment: **Hint:** The inequality given says
$$
1+\color{#C00}{\frac1n}\le e^{\color{#C00}{1/n}}
$$
Raise both sides to the $n^\text{th}$ power.

Answer (score 1):

$y = x+1$ is the tangent line to $y = e^x$ when $x= 0$.  Since $e^x$ is convex ($\frac{d^2}{dx^2} e^x=e^x>0$), it always remains above its tangent lines. Therefore, $1+x \le e^x$ for all $x$. Then, substitute $x=1/n$ in this equation.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that but when I multiply the LHS by $e^n$, how do I work that? I've tried subbing 1+n in for that but it does not leave me with anything I think is useful?

Comment: $1+1/n\le e^n.$ Now, take the $n$the root of both sides. $(1+n)^{1/n}\le e$

Comment: I might be misunderstanding here, but when subbing in x= 1/n, would you not get 1+1/n≤e^(1/n) which leads to (1+1/n)$e^n$ ≤e?

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes, that will happen. Then, take the $n$th power of both sides. (Ok since $n$ is positive)

Comment: Thanks. Was my bad that I couldn't just see that though

Answer (score 1):

What if you use Bernoulli's inequality:

$1+ny \leq (1+y)^{n}$ for any natural n.

So plugging $y= \frac{x}{n}$, we get

$1+x \leq (1+\frac{x}{n})^n \leq e$ for $x\geq -1$.

The inequality follows trivially for $x<-1$ as the LHS is negative, while exp is non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

I think the intention of the proof is as follows:

$$n\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right) \stackrel{1+x \leq e^x}{\leq}n \ln e^{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{n}{n} = 1$$